# Angular Property binding ngForTrack not used by any directive

Tags: html, angular, ngfor, angular6

I'm working on converting an angular 1.x site to angular 2.6 and I'm trying to get some text and a URL to showup and I've got the following code from the old site :

```
<div ng-repeat="item in cartCtrl.downloadFinishedItems track by $index">
    <div class="links-14">
        <a ng-show="item.downloadJob.downloadLink"
              ng-click="cartCtrl.downloadFile(item)">{{item.name}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I convert to :

```
<div *ngFor="let item of downloadFinishedItems track by $index">
    <div class="links-14">
        <a [hidden]="!item.downloadJob.downloadLink"
            (click)="downloadFile(item)">{{item.name}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I get the following error :

[image: What am I missing here?]

Is the new equivalent of that line? :

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of downloadFinishedItems; index as i; trackBy:i">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [the NgForOf documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#change-propagation):

> To customize the default tracking algorithm, *NgForOf* supports *trackBy*
>   option. *trackBy* takes a function which has two arguments: *index* and
>   *item*. If *trackBy* is given, Angular tracks changes by the return value
>   of the function.

In your case, it would be:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of downloadFinishedItems; trackBy: trackByIndex">
```

with the method:

```
trackByIndex(index, item) {
  return index;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the link to the doc and the clear answer.